# Using MongoDB Views with a filter expression

Tags: mongodb, view, match, pipeline, projection

i want to make use of MongoDB Views, but from my point of view, views in MongoDB seem to be made just for "static" use cases where the $match condition is set up front. Mongo does not seem to be able to push down a filter criteria properly to the $match stage even in simple aggregation pipelines.
In particular, when using a "$Project" aggregation pipeline stage, I have observed that MongoDB no longer uses the underlying collection indexes. Let's give a simple example

My view consists of only 2 fields which are the same field in the underlying collection. The collection has round about 35 Million records and the field *Metadata.Lotnumber* is indexed

```
$project: {
'Metadata.Lotnumber': 1,
Lot: '$Metadata.Lotnumber'
}
```

After creating the view i queried the view two times

1. Filtering the view with the expression

   {"Metadata.Lotnumber":"1234"}

--> the queryresult (40 docs) is back instantly (index must have been used)
3. Filtering the view with expression

```
{"Lotnumber":"1234"}
```

--> takes round about 8 seconds for the first 20 docs

My main question is: Does anybody of you know if there is a kind of documentation which aggregation stages can be used without loosing the possibility to push down the filter criteria properly to the "$match" stage (first stage in the aggregation pipeline).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [Behavior of Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/#behavior) for additional info, like usage of indexes, etc.

Comment: @prasad_: Thanks for the hint, but i have already read the MongoDB documentation regarding views. Unfortunately the statements there are too general and do not even touch my question at all

Comment: Use `explain` to see how the query is processed.  When I ran a quick test on  querying a renamed field in a view, it did query the original field.